# Installing VLC cli on Synology NAS

Tags: linux, vlc, nas, cvlc

I am trying to install VLC CLI on a Synology NAS (DS212j) so that I can record live events for later playback.

If there is a better venue for this question, please point me in the right direction.

Anyway, I am able to use VLC CLI on Linux, OS X, and Windows to record the stream as an MP3.  What I would like do is use my Synology - which is "always on" - to record the stream.

At a predetermined time, it will run a bash script which will write the podcast XML file and move them to a public directory so that I can download from anywhere in the world.

Any help doing this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As the synology uses a non-standard linux environment and CPU architecture, it isn't as simple as dropping a binary on the box. However, vlc can be installed via optware on the synology, which is (relatively) simple to setup. You can see that vlc is available in optware here: http://ipkg.nslu2-linux.org/feeds/optware/cs08q1armel/cross/unstable/

To setup optware, refer to the following wiki: http://forum.synology.com/wiki/index.php/Overview_on_modifying_the_Synology_Server,_bootstrap,_ipkg_etc

Comment: Thanks for the post...I am going to give that a shot tonight.